# Fast way to convert ARGB texture to next power of 2 texture

Tags: c++, opengl, c++11

We have some old devices that don't support non-pot textures and we have a function that converts ARGB textures to next power of 2 texture. The problem is that it's quite slow and we're wondering if there is a better approach to convert these textures.

```
void PotTexture()
{
    size_t u2 = 1; while (u2 < imageData.width) u2 *= 2;
    size_t v2 = 1; while (v2 < imageData.height) v2 *= 2;

    std::vector<unsigned char> pottedImageData;
    pottedImageData.resize(u2 * v2 * 4);

    size_t y, x, c;
    for (y = 0; y < imageData.height; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < imageData.width; x++)
        {
            for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                pottedImageData[4 * u2 * y + 4 * x + c] = imageData.convertedData[4 * imageData.width * y + 4 * x + c];
            }
        }
    }

    imageData.width = u2;
    imageData.height = v2;
    std::swap(imageData.convertedData, pottedImageData);
}
```

On some devices this can easily use 100% of the CPU so any optimizations would be amazing. Are there any existing functions that I could look at that perform this conversion?

Edit:

I've optimized the above loop slightly to:

```
for (y = 0; y < imageData.height; y++)
{
    memcpy(
        &(pottedImageData[y * u2 * 4]), 
        &(imageData.convertedData[y * imageData.width * 4]), 
        imageData.width * 4);
}
```

Comment: Use `memcpy` for your optimisation, rather than `memmove`, since you know that the source and destination buffers can not overlap.

Comment: @PaulR I was just about to post the same thing. In our tests `memcpy` was much faster.

Comment: OK - well at this point I expect you're pretty much memory bandwidth limited, so I don't think there's much more you can do at this level. However it looks like you now have a more "holistic" solution in the answer below, so I guess the code optimisation is now redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even devices that don't support NPOT texture should support NPOT load.

Create the texture as an exact power of 2 and NO CONTENT using `glTexImage2D`, passing a null pointer for *data*.

> `data` may be a null pointer. In this case, texture memory is allocated to accommodate a texture of width `width` and height `height`. You can then download subtextures to initialize this texture memory. The image is undefined if the user tries to apply an uninitialized portion of the texture image to a primitive.

Then use `glTexSubImage2D` to upload a NPOT image, which occupies only a portion of the total texture.  This can be done without any CPU-side image rearrangement.

Comment: This approach does have some limitations, which may or may not be a problem depending on the exact use case. Wrap modes like `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` and `REPEAT` will not work as people might expect. Also, using mipmapping with such partly occupied textures is problematic, and will most likely not give the desired results if you're not very careful.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: While that's true, all those limitations also apply to the CPU-side rearrangement as done in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Having had a similar problem in a program I wrote, I took a very different approach. Rather than stretch the source texture, I just copied it into the top left corner of an otherwise empty power-of-two texture.

Then in the pixel shader you use a pair of floats to adjust s,t values so you fetch from just the top left corner.

```
float sAdjust = static_cast<float>(textureWidth) / static_cast<float>(containerWidth)
float tAdjust = static_cast<float>(textureHeight) / static_cast<float>(containerHeight)
```

is how you compute them, and to use them you'll get a Vec2 holding the s,t coordinates, just multiply s by sAdjust and t by tAdjust before using them to fetch.  If you're using Direct3D, it'd be something akin to this:

```
D3DXVECTOR4 stAdjust;
stAdjust.x = sAdjust;
stAdjust.y = tAdjust;
// Transfer stAdjust into a float4 inside your pixel shader, call it stAdjust in there
```

Now in the pixel shader assume you have:

```
float2 texcoord;
float4 stAdjust;
```

you just say:

```
texcoord.x = texcoord.x * stAdjust.x;
texcoord.y = texcoord.y * stAdjust.y;
```

before using texcoord.  Sorry I can't tell you how to do this in GLSL, but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the very first optimization can be done here:

> ```
> size_t u2 = 1; while (u2 < imageData.width) u2 *= 2;
> size_t v2 = 1; while (v2 < imageData.height) v2 *= 2;
> ```

What you want to do is (for each dimension) find the floor of the logarithm-base2 (log2) and put that into 2**n+1. The standard math library has function `log2` but it operates on floating point. But we can use is. 2**n can be written as `1 << n`. So this gives

```
size_t const dim_p2_… = 1 << (int)floor(log2(dim_…)+1);
```

Better but not yet ideal, because of that float conversion. The Bit Twiddling hacks document has a few functions for integer ilog2: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog

But we're still not optimal. Let me introduce you to Compiler intrinsics, which translate into machine instructions, if the machine in question can do it on the metal.

- GNU GCC: `int __builtin_ffs (unsigned int x)`, which returns one plus the index of the least significant 1-bit of x, or if x is zero, returns zero.
- MSVC++: `_BitScanReverse`, which returns the length of the run of the most significant bits set zero. So _BitScanReverse is like builtin_ffs - 1 (there's also a builtin_clz which behaves exactly like BitScanReverse.

So we can do

```
#define ilog2_p1(x) (__builtin_ffs(x))
```

or

```
#define ilog2_p1(x) (__BitScanReverse(x)+1)
```

and use that.

```
size_t const dim_p2_… = 1 << (int)floor(ilog2_p1(dim_…));
```

While we're at bit twiddling: We can save that whole ordeal if a texture is already in power of two format. A few years ago I (independently) rediscovered the wonderfully portable bit twiddling trick, exploiting the properties of complement-2 integers. You can also find it in the bit twiddles document. But the type neutral, concise macro form is rarely seen. So here it is:

```
#define ISPOW2(x) ( (x) && !( (x) & ((x) - 1) ) )
```

You're using C++ so templates are in order:

```
template<typename T> bool ispow2(T const x) { return x && !( x & (x - 1) ); }
```

Then Ben Voight already told you, how to use `glTexSubImage2D` to load that into the texture. Also have a look at the `GL_ARB_texture_rectangle` extension, that allows to load NPOT textures, but without the ability for mipmapping and advanced filtering. But it might be a viable choice for you.

If you ever feel the need to scale the texture it's always worth looking into dual spaces. In this case the spatial frequency domain dual space. Upscaling a signal is essentially a impulse response. As such it can be described as a convolution. Convolutions usually are O(n²) in complexity. But due to the Fourier Convolution theorem in Fourier space the equivalent is simple multiplication, so it becomes O(n). FFT can be done with O(n log n), so the total complexity is about O(n + 2n log n), which is much better.